# What is the fastest way to pass around values in GLSL?

Tags: glsl

In GLSL shaders, I often want a couple of functions to modify a single value, for various reasons (e.g. a fragment shader that uses four functions to apply lighting, texture, speculars and fog, say). I can think of at least three ways to pass around such values for modification:

1. Use `inout` parameters for every function.
2. Pass the value as an `in` parameter and use the return value (which has the obvious disadvantage that I can only use one value).
3. Use a global variable that each function modifies.

Should I expect any practical differences between these methods? Are some more probably faster than others? Are some more compatible than others? Are there any other differences? Or other methods, for that matter?

Or can I simply choose the one I like best, stylistically?

Comment: Optimize your algorithm. Then optimize any other bottlenecks you find. After doing all of that, _then_ you can think about what methods of modifying parameters work best on a given compiler (because it _will_ be compiler-dependent). In general, you will get precisely zilch out of this.

Comment: The three methods you describe are likely to end up being the same if you have only a single shader in any given program stage.  If you link multiple shaders into a single stage, then using a global might be different (better or worse).  As always, you need to profile to figure out what (if anything) is different and where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Also, for #2, you can use `out` parameters to get (effectively) extra return values.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of optimization depends mostly on the underlying GLSL compiler. Profile your shader on different GPUs: AMD, nVidia, Intel and select the best codepath.